# Memory use visual monitoring

Tags: c, memory, profiling

I'm developing a program in C that uses a lot of memory and I need to monitor it. I know Netbeans has this option but I need to do this in Solaris Studio.

Do you know of a graphical tool to view the usage of memory, CPU and if possible, I/O?

How do you usually do these things?

PS: I know valgrind can search for memory leaks, but I'm looking for something more visual.

Comment: @Lou: the mention of valgrind would seem to indicate Linux.